# Read folders as files

Tags: python-3.x, file, directory

After doing some research and finding nothing, I wanted to ask:

**Is it possible to read folders as files?**

What i mean by this is, is it possible to read a folder as an object, like one can read a text file? (example below)

```
with open("sometext.txt", "r") as data:
    print(data)

fo = open("sometext.txt", "w")
information = "somestring"
fo.write(information)
fo.close()
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to do? Iterating over all files in a directory?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? You say you are writing a file, but do you mean you are trying to create a folder or write multiple files?

Comment: Does [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) do what you want?

Comment: Well, my intentions are to edit the folder as if it were an object, this way, I thought I could "corrupt" a folder, making in inaccessible and undo the work to make it accessible when needed. But as I initially thought, this may prove to be a stupid thought

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on some operating systems, but probably not in the way you intend.  There is a library [`directory`](https://github.com/pelotoncycle/directory) (disclaimer: I have never used this, I found it while researching your question) that binds the low-level system call [`opendir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/opendir.html) and [`readdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/readdir.html). These are C functions that interact with the Unix kernel to manipulate directories.

This is possible because in Unix, directories are a special type of file that contain pointers to the contents of that directory. This may be true of other operating systems, but I wouldn't count on there being existing tools for interacting with the low-level components of those systems with Python.

As the people who commented above have pointed out, there are *very few* (though not none) scenarios that would require you to get this close to the machinery of the operating system. It's likely that whatever you're trying to do can be done using either the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module or some other part of the standard library.

Comment: Do you think this could be used in a way that is presented in my previous comment?

Comment: No. To damage the directories you would need write to the directories. I doubt there's an existing Python library that can do what you want.  If you want to do this, you should be writing in a lower-level language, probably C, depending on the target filesystem. If you're going to pursue this further (it's an interesting idea), I would recommend a virtual machine or hosted instance running some very basic unix distribution.  Expect to render it absolutely unusable at least a few times.